# AngularJS: Dynamically loading HTML with a controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm working on a small project to get the hang of how things work.

Basically I want to have a single-page app where I can dynamically change part of the page to include html from some other file.  This other file has a controller and such.  I would like the url to stay the same.  I need the page to be loaded dynamically with a variable name.

Right now, I can get the HTML to load from the imported template, but a lot of HTML is excluded and all of the "ng" tags are gone.  I take this to mean that this new page can't find the controller or a lot of the stuff is getting compiled out or something. Maybe I'm not importing things in the correct order?  I have no idea. Here's my basic layout:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
    $scope.htmlContent = 'somepage.html';
    $scope.externalPage = 'otherpage';
    $scope.changePage = function(page) {
        $scope[page]();
    }
    $scope.otherpage = function() {
        $scope.htmlContent = 'otherpage.html';
    }
});

app.controller('InternalPage', function($scope) {
    alert('hello world');
    $scope.content = "This is not showing";
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
    <!-- This all works.  Clicking "Change Page" changes the 
         HTML referenced by the <div> tag -->

    <a ng-click="changePage(externalPage)">Change Page</a>
    <div ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
</div>
```

**otherpage.html**

```
<div ng-controller="InternalPage">
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</div>
```

I have tried including the javascript in the html file itself to no avail.  I also could not get the ng-include thing to work either.

Comment: you can't write this  $scope[page](); . This is not allowed in angular.

Comment: You can use $scope[page](), this is how I've implemented it and the function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into ng-include instead of ng-bind-html:
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp

Comment: If I put the controller inside app.js, will the imported file be able to read it?  Or will I have to put the javascript inside of the included file?

Comment: Yes. ng-include injects the content of the file into wherever you include it so any imports earlier in the file will be accessible there.